# Callback errors in Async library

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm using the `async` library together with mongoose as follows:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    async.map(new_tags, function(tag, callback) {
      Tag.findOneAndUpdate(
        { '_id': tag._id },
        { '$setOnInsert': { '_id': tag._id, 'name': tag.name } },
        { 'upsert': true, 'new': true },
        callback
      );
    }, callback);
  }, function(tags, callback) { 
    for(var k = 0; k < tags.length; k++) {
      res_tags.push(tags[k]._id);
    }
    callback(res_tags);
  }
],
function(err, results) {
  callback(err, results);
});
```

But I'm having doubts on how the catch the error at the end of `async.waterfall`... The code as it is will have in `err`, the actual resulting array (`res_tags`).

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling your callbacks appropriately. `async` uses error-first callbacks. This is an important concept in Node.js because this is considered the "best practice" for handling errors within a callback chain.

[See this post](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) on error-first callbacks and Node.js

See below for how to properly implement the callbacks within your code:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    var res
    async.map(new_tags, function(tag, callback) {
      Tag.findOneAndUpdate(
        { '_id': tag._id },
        { '$setOnInsert': { '_id': tag._id, 'name': tag.name } },
        { 'upsert': true, 'new': true },
        function (err, doc) {
          // If an error occurs, pass it back to our map callback.
          if (err) 
            return callback(err, null); 

          // If there was no error return the doc
          return callback(null, doc);
        }
      );
    }, function (err, docs) {
      // If an error occurred during map return it back to the waterfall
      if (err)
        return callback(err, null);

      // Return back all docs
      return callback(null, docs);
    });
  }, function(tags, callback) { 
    // For each tag push them to res_tags
    async.each(tags, function(tag) {
      res_tags.push(tags[k]._id);
    }, function(err) {
      if (err)
        return callback(err, null);

      return callback(null, res_tags);
    }); 
  }
],
function(err, results) {
  // If an error happened during any execution in waterfall catch it and handle it
  if (err)
    // Error handling 
  else
    return results; // No error, return our results
});
```

Comment: Hum, I see! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of each function callback in the waterfall should be an Error object or null if there were no errors.

```
callback(res_tags);
```

Should be changed to:

```
callback(null, res_tags);
```

From the documentation (https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall):

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Comment: No worries, it's worth noting that @peteb comment would be a more complete example to follow as currently you won't catch any errors from the findOneAndUpdate database function.

Comment: Yes, as @peteb posted his answer, I understood exactly what I was doing wrong! But thank you for your answer, as well :)